# Sequelize Postgres: error: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am getting an error of **error: sorry, too many clients already**

I'm also trying to use **pg bouncer** but I'm not able to fix this issue.

```
original: error: sorry, too many clients already
  at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/user/Desktop/www/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
  at Parser.handlePacket (/home/user/Desktop/www/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
  at Parser.parse (/home/user/Desktop/www/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/Desktop/www/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
  at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
  at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
  at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
  at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
  at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
length: 85,
severity: 'FATAL',
code: '53300',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: undefined,
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'proc.c',
line: '362',
routine: 'InitProcess'
```

Comment: Your database server has too many clients connected. You'll need to increase the maximum number of clients available (`max_connections` system variable). Adding pgBouncer in front won't help if it, too, can't connect to the database server.

Comment: i have already increase the max_connection value but still facing a same. issue but some time I'm also facing an error of Request Connection Timeout

Comment: Then look at the `pg_stat_activity` table – your database server simply seems overloaded with connections.

Comment: I'm not able to understand pg_stat_activity results.

Comment: Then you might want to paste the results in the post so we might help you.

Comment: I Have already attached the result response to my question.

Comment: The pg_stat_activity results you can't understand.

Comment: Maximum connection's status are showing `idle in transaction` state when I run pg stat quert

Comment: Well, then you have a lot of connections that are holding transactions open and not doing anything. That indicates a bug in some software connecting to your database.

Comment: Yes. I have fixed the issue by managing the transaction connections.